# Compare two HTML sources and highlight the differences on webpage

Tags: java, html, selenium

I have a requirement to compare two HTML pages differences. I am trying to figure out a way if i can compare the HTML source code of two webpages(almost similar), and show/highlight the differences visually(on UI) in java.
or in other way i can take screenshots, compare them and highlight the differences.

Now problem is how to calculate the differences and highlight the same. I have tried pixel by pixel comparison but that does n't come 
properly.....Another one i have tried is collecting html data from both the pages and highlighting the differences But it takes lot of time....is there anything else which can be tried??

Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Break the problem into pieces and solve it. Do we need to explain that?

Comment: you will find a way in selenium to take screenshots, but then will you be comparing UI manually through those shots?

Comment: yup that's the problem how to calculate the difference and highlight the differences. I have tried by using pixel by pixel comparison but that does n't come properly.....Another one i have tried is collecting html data from both the pages and highlighting the differences But it takes lot of time....is there anything else which can be tried??